# ¿Cómo crear un array de objetos a partir de una función?

Tags: javascript, array, object

Estoy intentado crear un array de objetos con esta función:

```
function identidad()
{
    this.nombre;
    this.apellido1;
    this.apellido2;
}


x =  new identidad()[10];
```

Pero esto último me da un error:

```
x[0].nombre = "Pedro";
```

Este es el error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

¿Cúal es la forma correcta de hacerlo?

Comment: Ese código no tiene mucho sentido. ¿Qué es lo que quieres hacer, realmente?

Comment: Quiero hacer diez copias del objeto, (un array, un vector)... tal y como se haría con una estructutura en C y C++

Comment: ¿estás intentando crear un array de 10 identidades para luego inicializar sus valores?

Comment: si, eso es!! exacto!!

Comment: creo que en js no hay una manera directa de hacerlo, podrias inicializar una array y despues con un for meter 10 objetos

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Javascript **no** es C. No es necesario inicializar un array de determinadas posiciones para luego rellenar sus campos. Si sabes que quieres crear un array de 10 identidades, sabrás qué identidades son exactamente, así que puedes hacer.

```js
class Identidad {
  constructor(nombre, apellido1, apellido2){
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.apellido1 = apellido1;
    this.apellido2 = apellido2;
    }
}
let identidades = [];
identidades.push(new Identidad("Pedro","apellido1","apellido2"));
console.log(identidades);
```

Comment: muchas gracias!!! voy a probarlo!!

Answer (score 2):

Tendrías que inicializar el array de objetos primero y luego asignarle los valores:

Tienes muchas opciones. Te pongo aquí un par (como ves inicializo los objetos con valores vacíos pero podrías pasarle valores a la función o directamente pasarle el objeto y hacer el `push` en el `array`):

1. Bucle `for` tradicional:

```js
function identidad(numItems)
{
    let arr = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < numItems; i++) {
        arr.push({
            nombre: "",
            apellido1: "",
            apellido2: ""
        });
    }
    return arr;
}
x =  new identidad(10);
x[0].nombre = "Pedro";
console.log(x);
```

2. Utilizando ES6

```js
function identidad(numItems)
{
    return new Array(numItems).fill().map((e,i) => {
       return {nombre: "",apellido1:"",apellido2:""}
    });
}
x =  new identidad(10);
x[0].nombre = "Pedro";
console.log(x);
```

Comment: Madre mia!! Entre tu respuesta y la de @dteterevkov me he quedado en shock!! :-) Voy a probarlas... gracias a los dos!!

Answer (score 1):

Prueba esto:

```
function identidad() {
    this.nombre;
    this.apellido1;
    this.apellido2;
}
var x =  new Array();

x[0] = new identidad();

x[0].nombre = "Pedro";
```

Comment: Ese constructor no hace nada, es lo mismo que si hiciera `x[0]={}`

Comment: Porque así está montada la función, pero al final se consigue lo que Iván pretende, dar valor a `x[0].nombre`

Comment: Me olvidaba de darte las gracias a ti tambien... No me esperaba de que hubiese tantas formas de hacer lo mismo... voy a probar todas las respuestas que me habeís dado!! Muchas gracias!!